# C - Triangle program not printing any output on call to main

Tags: c, printf, program-entry-point

I have written a C code that is supposed to print a triangle. A width and character are defined and the code should then print out a triangle of that with a fill of that character. I think there may be an error in main, but the code compiles fine. When I run it, there is no output.

Here is my code:

```
void triangle(int width, char x);

int main(void){
    triangle(4, c);
}

void triangle(int width, char x){
    if (width > 2){
        return;
    }
    int counter = 1;
    int direction = 1;
    do{
        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < width - counter; i++){
            printf(" ");
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++){
            printf("%c", x);
        }
        printf("\n");
        counter += direction;
        if(counter > width){
            counter = width - 1;
            direction = -1;
        }
    }while (counter != 1);
    return;
}
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: You have more than 1 error in your code: what is c? a global variable? It should be 'c' if you want to pass it as character. Then your triangle function will immediately exit because width (4) is bigger than 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry if this wasn't clear in the question.
The expected output should be a triangle of width (and height) of 4, with a fill of 'c'.

So I think I have figured it out.
I must use the < operator (silly human error) and the character must have a single quote: 'c'.

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
 if (width > 2){
        return;
 }
```

and the call is

```
 triangle(4, c);
```

This explains the no output. 
There are other error as well, but you first try working them out yourself maybe?